# Where is Xamarin.Forms.Theme.Base Nuget Package

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to try out the new `DataPages` feature of Xamarin Forms as announced at evolve 2016.

However, a key Nuget `Xamarin.Forms.Theme.Base` is not showing up on Nuget

Does anyone know when this will be available ?

Comment: You're right, the Theme.Base package is mentioned in the Release Notes for Pre-1, but I don't see the actual package.

Comment: The separate nuget for the `CarouselView` that was pulled out of the Xamarin.Forms nuget package is also not available. There was some Xam forum posting that they were trying to get to it Friday, but with the devs in transit from Evolve... I'm assuming Monday now...

Answer (score 6):

We have not pushed it to NuGet just yet, but it should be done in the coming days.

Update: The Xamarin.Forms.Theme.Base package is [now available on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.Theme.Base/).

Comment: Is today that day? :-)

Comment: It is! Updating the answer to reflect the fact.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking at applying themes to my Xamarin application, after reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/themes/) post, it also guided me to the nuget package which i could not find. I see now, as of April 2018, the nuget package is there, even though it does not seemed to be indexed by nuget (cannot find it through `Visual studio`'s `Manage Nuget Packages` feature).

I see the current version is still tagged as being a "pre-release" version even after 2 years? I am sceptical as to how reliable this package is if it has not been worked on since 2016.

I would suggest having a look at [this blog post](https://blog.xamarin.com/easy-app-theming-with-xamarin-forms-styles/) for a good basis on how to apply themes at runtime